# What is the Cisco iOS (CLI) command to display a WAP's Radio MAC address?

Tags: cisco, command-line-interface, ios, mac-address

I can't believe I'm unable to find this with teh g00glez or by RTFMing, but does anyone know how to display the MAC address of a Cisco WAP's Radio (wifi connection) from the command line?

`show version` is nice enough to tell me that I have 2 Radios, a FastEthernet interface, and even give me the MAC address of the FastEthernet interface, but that's completely useless for correlating these things up to the MAC addresses recorded by our wireless surveys, which, for obvious reasons, have the MAC address of the radios, rather than the wired connection.

On the off chance it matters, these are 1242 AG Aironet WAPs (`AIR-AP1242AG-A-K9`), running assorted version 12.x K9 iOSes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to a nice sock in chat, I found the answer to this after I'd already typed up the question.  The painfully obvious answer is `show interfaces`.  Good ol' shint.

```
   Hopless-WAP#sh int
   [...]
    Dot11Radio0 is up, line protocol is up
      Hardware is 802.11G Radio, address is feed.face.beef (bia beef.face.feed)
      MTU 1500 bytes, BW 54000 Kbit, DLY 1000 usec,
         reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
      Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
      ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
      Last input 11:49:55, output 11:47:06, output hang never
      Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
      Input queue: 0/1127/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 3611
      Queueing strategy: fifo
      Output queue: 0/30 (size/max)
      5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
      5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
      [...]
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try

```
show dot11 bssid
```

My output is like(multiple SSID configured):

```
Interface      BSSID         Guest  SSID
Dot11Radio1   0026.ca7a.1f80  Yes  NLS-CORP-LAN
Dot11Radio1   0026.ca7a.1f81  No   NLS-TEMP1
Dot11Radio1   0026.ca7a.1f82  Yes  NLS-WEP64
Dot11Radio1   0026.ca7a.1f83  Yes  NLS-WPA-PSK
Dot11Radio0   0026.cab5.9270  Yes  NLS-CCJY
Dot11Radio0   0026.cab5.9271  Yes  NLS-CORP-LAN
Dot11Radio0   0026.cab5.9272  Yes  NLS-LEAP-TEST
Dot11Radio0   0026.cab5.9273  No   NLS-TEMP
Dot11Radio0   0026.cab5.9274  No   NLS-TEMP1
Dot11Radio0   0026.cab5.9275  Yes  NLS-WEP64
Dot11Radio0   0026.cab5.9276  Yes  NLS-WPA-PSK
Dot11Radio0   0026.cab5.9277  Yes  NLS-WPA2-AES
Dot11Radio0   0026.cab5.9278  Yes  NLS-WPA2-MIX
```

Screen shot below:

[image]